# Euler characteristic of a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it a complete coincidence that the Euler characteristic of a curve is exactly twice the Euler characteristic of its structure sheaf?

Comment: Google "Hodge diamond". This question will get closed, I am afraid.

Comment: I think it would be a shame to close this question. Something whose explanation comes from Hodge theory and Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch doesn't "belong" at M.SE.

Comment: I agree.  I always found the closely related result of Riemann's that a curve of genus g has g holomorphic differentials, beautiful and not obvious.  The fact that global holomorphic functions are constant, bounds the number above by g (by integration over cycles), but how to produce g of them? Riemann just wrote them down in the plane as adjoint polynomials, and in general people often just do this by proving the full Riemann Roch theorem.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I should say that my comment about closing was meant just to prepare the OP, not as a recommendation. (Leaving aside that issue, I would say there are plenty of questions at this level on MSE.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble However, classical and simplest application of Hodge theory isn't exactly research level math either. I admit a certain contradiction here, but probably a research level mathematician is supposed to be able to google such a thing.

Comment: @roysmith: I think that is the real core of this question: why is the dimension of $H^0(\Omega^1)$ equal to the topological genus? I would like to see a full answer to that, if you care to expand your comment!

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev There are plenty of research mathematicians who may stumble upon a phenomenon in an area where they are not expert. MathOverflow is tailor-made for such mathematicians to get expert responses, often even more illuminating than what they might find through Google searches. (I often feel we've drifted too far away from the original vision of MO, which was really exactly in view of such situations.)

Comment: Integrating differential forms over cycles gives a holomorphic function if there are no periods.  Since there are 2g periods, > 2g forms would give a global holomorphic function, and you must double the number of holomorphic forms to count their conjugates.  so there ≤ g holom forms.  In the plane they are given by polynomials of degree d-3, as Riemann stated. Shafarevich does this for hyperelliptic curves in his book Basic Algebraic Geometry chap. III.5.5, 1974, and it is in general in Griffiths Intro to Alg Curves chap. III.2.  Note on P^2, h^0(d-3) = (1/2)(d-1)(d-2) = g.

Comment: The explicit analytic work on constructing differentials, both meromorphic and holomorphic, is carried out in some detail in classical books on Riemann surfaces, such as Siegel topics in cx func theory (employing a dissection of the surface) vol II.4.2, Weyl Concept of a Riemann surface II.15, and Springer Introd to Riemann surfaces chap.8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To spell out potentially dense's comment, the Hodge theorem tells you that 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
H^0(X, \mathbb{C}) &\cong& H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \\
H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) &\cong& H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \oplus H^0(X, \Omega^1) \\
H^2(X, \mathbb{C}) &\cong& H^1(X, \Omega^1) \\
\end{array}$$
where the left hand sides are topological cohomology and the right hand sides are sheaf cohomology.

Serre duality tells us that $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \cong H^0(X, \Omega^1)^{\vee}$ and $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \cong H^1(X, \Omega^1)^{\vee}$. So
$$\dim H^0(X, \mathbb{C}) - \dim H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) + \dim H^2(X, \mathbb{C}) = 2 \left( \dim H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) - \dim H^1(X, \mathcal{O}) \right)$$
as desired.

Answer (score 12):

It is a consequence of the [Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem).

In fact, for any line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ on a complete curve $X$ we have $$\chi(\mathscr{L}) = c_1(\mathscr{L}) + \frac{1}{2} \int_X c_1(T_X).$$

Taking $\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{O}_X$ and recalling that the integral over $X$ of the top Chern class of the tangent bundle is the topological Euler number $\chi_{\textrm{top}}(X)$, we obtain $$2 \chi(\mathscr{O}_X) = \chi_{\textrm{top}}(X).$$

Comment: Why do you call it HRR, rather than just RR? Because of the Chern classes? I think most people reserve Hirzebruch for the generalization to higher dimensions and don't distinguish 1d variants.

Comment: @Ben: I always called HRR the version involving the Chern character and the Todd genus, even in the case of curves (where, of course, it is equivalent to the "classical" RR).

Comment: @Francesco.  I am still puzzled.  If you are referring to say the version of HRR in Fulton's Intersection theory, Cor.15.2.1, p,288, expressing χ(L) in terms of the chern character of L and todd class of the tangent bundle, it seems to me this differs from the "classical" RRT as proved by Roch.  I.e. it looks as if the definition of χ(L) involves the first cohomology group of L rather than the space of differential forms vanishing on the divisor of a section of L.  So it looks to me as if even for curves, classical RR is HRR plus Serre duality.  Does this seem right?

Comment: @roy: well, I used "classical RR", but I should have written instead "usual RR", meaning the version without Chern classes $$\chi(D)=1-g + \deg(D).$$ You are right that the "classical" RR (in the sense of the version proven by "classical geometers") $$l(D)-i(D)=1-g+\deg(D)$$
involves $i(D)=h^0(K-D)$, so one needs Serre duality in order to identify the latter space with $h^1(D).$
Thank you for your remark.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, I get it now. The words "classical RR" have taken on a new meaning for those of us educated via sheaf theory! I mention it because to me this was the big advance of modern times, to move from classical RR, i.e. computing h^0(L), to the easier question of computing χ(L), easier since it is a topological invariant. But I like to remind myself that these HRR theorems still leave open the hard problem, of computing the cohomology groups. (I know, in future I will try to use the term "original RR".)

Answer (score 7):

The answers that this follows from Hodge theory and HRR are of course spot on.  If what is meant is rather why those theorems are true, here is a short proof at least of HRR for curves:

If two smooth plane curves have the same degree, hence the same topology, they are linearly equivalent, so by the exact sheaf sequence (of a divisor on a surface) also have the same chi(O).  So chi(O) is a topological invariant for smooth plane curves.  But why does it equal 1-genus?

In degree one, both (1-genus) and chi(O) are equal to 1.  Moreover when you add a general line L to raise the degree of a curve C from n to n+1, the topological genus of the (smoothed) curve goes up by n-1, so (1-genus) goes down by n-1.  By the exact sequence relating the structure sheaf of the sum C+L of these divisors, to the sum of their structure sheaves, chi(O) also goes down by n-1.

Thus both invariants are the same for degree one curves and change the same way when we raise degree, hence they agree.  But all curves are at least nodal plane curves, and we can modify the argument to allow for the nodes.

As to why there exist g holomorphic differentials, by taking real and imaginary parts this is equivalent to why there are 2g harmonic differentials.  I.e. we are trying to understand why Hodge’s theorem is true.  As mentioned, the maximum modulus principle implies a non zero harmonic form must have non zero period over some loop, and a harmonic form is uniquely determined by its periods over all homology cycles.  Thus existence of harmonic forms means finding ones with prescribed periods.  This is done in two steps.  The first step is to find a smooth form with given periods.  This is done by putting a collar around a non separating loop, forming a smooth function that climbs from 0 to 1 when crossing the collar, setting it equal to zero elsewhere, and taking d of it.  Thus we see that topology does tell us how many smooth closed forms we can construct that are cohomologically independent.  Then the deep part, i.e. the Hodge theory, says that each such smooth closed form can be written as a sum of a harmonic form and an exact form.  For details see Springer chapters 7 and 8 page 207, lemma 8-1, especially using Weyl’s smoothing lemma 7.3 p. 199.

To “see” why this occurs, one may view the flow diagrams in Springer’s chapter 1 (fig.1.27. p.27), taken from Klein’s lectures on Riemann surfaces.  I.e. it seems a differential form, or covector field, is determined by its flow lines, and when these flow lines are of minimal length in some sense, then they satisfy the Laplace equation and hence are harmonic.  So the intuitively plausible fact that these lines may be allowed to deform within a cohomology class until they are minimal (Dirichlet principle), suggests the existence of a harmonic form in each cohomology class (???  I just made this up, but maybe some expert will help out here.)

It seems Riemann reduced this problem to the “Dirichlet problem” of existence of a harmonic function with prescribed boundary conditions, on the polygon of 4g sides obtained by dissecting the genus g Riemann surface by 2g transverse cuts.  One constructs a harmonic function f which agrees on opposite pairs of sides except on one pair where it differs by a ≠ 0 constant on the two identified edges.  Then taking df gives a harmonic differential with a non trivial period.  Since there are 2g choices of such paired sides, and a harmonic form is determined by its periods, one can construct exactly 2g independent harmonic differentials this way, hence g holomorphic differentials.